Digit Factorial Chains - Why does every number fall into a loop?
I am currently doing Project Euler problem 74.Now I am not here to ask how to resolve the problem itself, but another aspect.
For those who don't know, here's the problem statement

The number $145$ is well known for the property that the sum of the factorial of its digits is equal to $145$: $1! + 4! + 5! = 145$
Perhaps less well known is $169$, in that it produces the longest chain of numbers that link back to $169$; it turns out that there are only three such loops that exist:
$$ 169 \rightarrow 363601 \rightarrow 1454 \rightarrow 169 \\
871 \rightarrow 45361 \rightarrow 871 \\
872 \rightarrow 45362 \rightarrow 872
$$
It is not difficult to prove that EVERY starting number will eventually get stuck in a loop. For example, ... (the rest of the problem)

The claim (which I highlighted in bold) would mean that there exists no number $N$ so that when you apply this process it flies off to infinity (because if it converges like the Collatz Sequence it can still create a loop). How did the PE problem writers / developers / etc derive or proof this claim. I have genuinely no idea, so if you can help, thanks in advance!

The idea (in case it's not obvious to you): Let the sequence be $a_i$. For a given $a_1$ (your N), show that there exists an $N, M$ such that for any $n > N$, we have $a_n < M$. Then by pigeonhole principle, the eventual period is $< M$ and we are stuck in a loop. $\quad$ Hint: If $a_i< 10^k$ , then $a_{i+1} \leq k \times 9!$.

See https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.06691

Have you had a look at that link, duc?

I saw it, but I think I still prefer the explaination by the answer I accepted, because it's simpler, I guess. I also think that's a nice explaination by itself tho

Some notation : for $N \in \mathbb N$ let $f(N)$ be the sum of the factorials of the digits of $N$.
Let $N$ be an $n$ digit number with $n$ fixed. Then, $f(N)$ is the largest when each of its digits is $9$. Therefore, $f(n) \leq 9! \times n = 362880n$. Note that $n$ is the number of digits of $N$ which is at most $\lceil\log_{10}N\rceil + 1$.
Since $\lim_{N \to \infty}\frac{362880(\lceil\log_{10}N\rceil + 1)}{N} = 0$, we can find an integer $M$ such that for $m>M$, $$f(m) \leq 362880(\lceil\log_{10}m\rceil + 1) < m.$$
Thus, $f(m)< m$ for any $m>M$.

We first claim that for any $1 \leq x \leq M$, the sequence $x,f(x),f(f(x)),\ldots$ eventually becomes a cycle.
What is our strategy? Let $f^l$ refers to $f$ applied $l$ times e.g. $f^0(x) = x$, $f^1(x) = f(x)$ and $f^2(x) = f(f(x))$. Then, suppose that $f^l(x) = f^m(x)$ for some $m>l$. It automatically follows that $f^{l+k}(x) = f^{m+k}(x)$ for all $k \geq 1$, so that the sequence $f^i(x)$ contains a cycle whose first iteration is from $f^l(x)$ to $f^m(x)$, the second iteration is from $f^m(x)$ to $f^{2m-l}(x)$, and the $(L+1)$th iteration is from $f^{m+L(m-l)}(x)$ to $f^{m+(L+1)(m-l)}(x)$.
So all we need to show is that there exist $l<m$ such that $f^l(x) = f^m(x)$. We will use the pigeonhole principle.
Let $M' = \max\{f(x) : 1 \leq x \leq M\}$. Recall if $m>M$ then $f(m)<m$.
Now, for any $1 \leq x\leq M'$, look at the sequence $x,f(x),f^2(x),\ldots, f^{M'-M}(x)$. If $x>M$ then $f(x)<x$, so $1 \leq f(x) < x \leq M'$. Similarly, if $f(x) > M$ then $1 \leq f^2(x) < f(x) < x \leq M'$. Because there are at most $M'-M$ values in between $M$ and $M'$, we must have that at least one of the values $x,f(x),\ldots,f^{M'-M}(x)$ lies in between $1$ and $M$.

Now we are ready to apply the pigeonhole principle. Let $1 \leq x \leq M$. Consider the sequence of numbers $$
x,f(x),f^2(x),\ldots,f^{(M+1)(M'-M)+M}(x).
$$
Now, between $x,f(x),\ldots,f^{M'-M}(x)$, there is at least one number between $1$ and $M$. Call this number $1 \leq X_0 \leq M$.
For any $1 \leq L \leq M$, of the numbers $f^{L(M'-M)+L}(x),f^{L(M'-M)+2}(x),\ldots,f^{(L+1)(M'-M)+L}(x)$, there is at least one number between $1$ and $M$. Call this number $1 \leq X_L \leq M$.
Thus, we have $M+1$ numbers $1\leq X_0,X_1,\ldots,X_L \leq M$. It follows that two of these must be the same, say $X_m = X_n$. But, each $X_i$ is of the form $f^{k_i}(x)$ for some integer $k_i$. Thus, we conclude that $f^l(x) = f^m(x)$ for some $1 \leq l <m \leq (M+1)(M'-M)+M$.
It follows that iterations of $f$ beginning from every $1 \leq x \leq M$ always fall into a cycle.

What about $x>M$? We effectively covered that in our proof above : if $x>M$ then $f(x) < x$. In particular, one of the numbers $x,f(x),f(f(x)),\ldots, f^{x-M}(x)$ will be in between $1$ and $M$. Then, using our previous result, further iterations must eventually lead to a cycle, giving the proof.
